# Variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, variables

I am junior and have a simple code.
I want to get value of final tempo with "one" without losing both of function, can I get it ? 
if yes, how can I do this ?
Thanks for the answer

```
var tempo;
object();

function object(){
    tempo = "one";

    array();

}

function array(){
    tempo = "two";
}

alert(tempo);
```

Sorry for my bad english

Comment: change the order, `array();tempo = "one";`

Comment: Downvoting for the title... And what do you mean "without losing"? Note that when you call `object()` you also call `array()`, then at the time of the `alert(tempo)`, `tempo` value is already `two`.

Comment: @ahmad: Have I answered your question?

Comment: Well the questions is, why you want to do this? Why do you want to set `tempo` to `two` without using this information, and why you want that it is `one` later again?  Your script above in combination with your requirement does not make that much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you find this somewhere in interview questions and there are few probable solutions where you need to small changes

**1)** call array function first in object() function

```
var tempo;
object();

function object(){
    array();
    tempo = "one";
}

function array(){
    tempo = "two";
}

alert(tempo);
```

I guess you find this somewhere in interview questions and there are few probable solutions where you need to small changes

**2)** Make tempo of second function as local variable by adding var before it

```
var tempo;
object();

function object(){
    tempo = "one";
    array();
}

function array(){
    var tempo = "two";
}

alert(tempo);
```